# VBA: rename subsequential sheets with macro in order to keep counting

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have n sheets of the form:

> mySheet_1, mySheet_2,...,mySheet_n

In your opinion, given a number `j` between 1 and n which is the most efficient way to remove

> mySheet_j

and rename all the following sheets so that they are correctly ordered from

> mySheet_1 to mySheet_(n-1)

So for instance, if I have

> mySheet_1, mySheet_2, mySheet_3 and mySheet_4

if j is 2 in a first moment I have

> mySheet_1, mySheet_3, mySheet_4

(and this is easy I just need to remove mySheet_2) but now how can i rename mySheet_3 so that it becomes mySheet_2 and the same for mySheet_4 (that becomes mySheet_3)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this, although it does depend on the actual names of your sheets.

```
Sub x()

Dim j As Long, i As Long, k As Long

j = 2 ' the sheet to be deleted
k = Sheets("mySheet_" & j).Index
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("mySheet_" & j).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

For i = k To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Name = "mySheet_" & Split(Sheets(i).Name, "_")(1) - 1
Next i

End Sub
```